# git status returns "fatal: Not a git repository" yet .git directory exists

Tags: git

I have a remote folder that I am currently unable to push to. When I go directly to the remote directory and a do a 'git status' it reads:

> fatal: Not a git repository

The .git folder does exists and it was working fine yesterday and nothing has changed since.

Can anyone tell me the reason(s) why I might receive this message even though the .git folder exists?

Thanks in advance for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: missing rights on the .git directory ?

Comment: If not what @Rufinus suggests quite appropriately, possibly file system corruption...

Comment: what is the msg you get when to try to push?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've compared the permissions to another .git repository on the same server and they match exactly

Comment: The error I get when pusshing is as follows:

fatal: '/var/www/vhosts/X.co.uk/httpdocs': unable to chdir or not a git archive
Pushing to root@X.co.uk:/var/www/vhosts/X.co.uk/httpdocs
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: also can you run `git --config -l` and put the lines related to remote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the permissions on the .git folder are fine, see that there is a file `.git/HEAD` existing or is not named wrongly like `.git/head`. The presence of `.git/HEAD` ( or HEAD in case of bare) is the secondary check for a git repository

Comment: If `.git/HEAD` exists and you still get this error, ensure that the *content* of `.git/HEAD` points to a valid reference. If git cannot parse the content, it also outputs that the repository is invalid.

Comment: what is .git/HEAD does not exist? (in my case only .git/ORIG_HEAD exists) and I'm having the same problem as the OP.

Comment: @SeanAhrens I had a corrupted `HEAD` file, and a fine `ORIG_HEAD` file. Copying the latter over the former fixed my issue and got me back into a correct state. You could run `git reflog` to see recent HEAD positions once that's done, in case you need to reset to a different commit.

Comment: Probably a good idea to run `git fsck --full` after such a manual recovery, just to check if there's any corruption.

Comment: [What can make git be unable to find the git repository even though the .git folder is there and the HEAD content is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77378610/3416774) I.e. what is the tertiary check?

Answer (score 1):

Clone the remote repository into another folder and compare the .git folders.
This will give you indication about missing or corrupted files.
You'll probably see a difference in the `objects` folder that you can ignore.

Comment: With such a test, differences in the `objects` folder are not necessarily a problem.

Comment: Correct, but in the other folders and files it may indicate what is the problem

Comment: @DrewNoakes, I've updated my answer for your comment. Thanks!

Comment: The content of several files may differ based upon what branch/commit was checked out, how many remotes there are, and what activity has been performed on the repo. `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `packed-refs`, `config`, `COMMIT_EDITMSG`... these can all be different and not a sign of problems. I upvoted your answer because it's interesting, but I'm not sure what actionable information such a diff could give to someone looking to solve corruption. I came here when my repo was corrupted, and the tip around checking the `HEAD` file contains a valid SHA-1 was enough for me to fix my problem, thankfully.