# Pushing git to server: Says "fatal:not a git repository"

Tags: git

I've set up my server with a bare git repo dev.git and public_html which contains my file structure. I have cloned into public_html successful but when I push from my local repo the following happens:

```
$git push dev master

username@server_address's password:
Enumerating objects: 11, done.
Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 505 bytes | 252.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '~/dev.git'
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '~/dev.git'
To server_address:dev.git
   some_numbers  master -> master
```

First of all, as far as I can tell, it is a git repository. That's almost certainly my error. Secondly I have a post receive hook which should run and echo something but doesn't. If I try to push again it says:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Even though nothing has changed.

Places I've looked:

- I searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434508/git-status-returns-fatal-not-a-git-repository-yet-git-directory-exists) but my dev.git folder has a HEAD
- It could be a persmissions issue, but I don't understand how to fix that anyway

Comment: `git remote show dev`