# What can make git be unable to find the git repository even though the .git folder is there and the HEAD content is correct?

Tags: git, git-head

Due to a syncing problem, I lost some files. I check `git status` and it says:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

But the `.git` folder still seems to be fine:

```
ls .git

    Directory: D:\QC supplements\Vaults\E Mạng lưới người thân, bạn bè của người có niềm tin tiêu cực\Liên minh Cueball\.git

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           26-Oct-23  3:35 PM                hooks
d----           26-Oct-23  3:35 PM                info
d----           26-Oct-23  3:35 PM                logs
d----           26-Oct-23  2:54 PM                objects
-a---           23-Mar-23  3:22 PM             13 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-a---           14-Apr-23  9:58 PM            261 config
-a---           23-Mar-23  3:19 PM             73 description
-a---           20-Apr-23  3:08 PM              0 FETCH_HEAD
-a---           23-Mar-23  3:19 PM             21 HEAD
-a---           14-May-23 12:19 PM        1925415 index
-a---           23-Mar-23  3:22 PM            103 packed-refs
```

I understand that some corrupts can happen inside the `.git` directory, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8434758/3416774), then the secondary check is the the content of the `HEAD`. But it's not corrupted as well:

```
ref: refs/heads/main
```

Then what other reasons for it to be unable to find the repo? Or in other words, what is the tertiary check?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: actually, what I said made no sense. I see no `refs` directory in that listing. Is it missing?

Comment: You mention "syncing". If you use Onedrive or similar cloud syncing tool for the .git directory, your repository is going to be destroyed in no time. Do not do that, or even more headaches ensue.

Comment: @j6t I use syncthing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `refs` directory is missing, and required.

edit: [the minimal is-it-a-repo smoketest](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/setup.c#L356) is almost startlingly simple:

1. a `HEAD` file with a commit id or a branch ref like `ref: refs/heads/itsabranch`
2. a `refs/` directory
3. an `objects/` directory *or* a `GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY` env pointing to one elsewhere.

and that's enough to make a working repository.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes this error is raised when you copy the .git directory from a different repo

```
git init .
```

Try initializing a new git repository in the required folder using the above command
and try git status

Comment: "sometimes" — when?

Comment: what i meant to say is your error is caused because you did the above mentioned scenario

Comment: I understand that in that scenario it's likely to get the error. However, the explanation that it only occurs when the `HEAD` file is corrupt. So is it correct to say that that explanation is not enough?

Comment: No [the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8434758/3416774)  you mentioned says that if the name of the `HEAD` is wrong this error will occur but from what i see the name and the contents of HEAD you mentioned are correct . So that explanation is not appropriate for your scenario

Comment: hmm, ok. I think the question can be reword as this: "The primary check for a git repo is existence of the `.git` directory. The secondary check is the `HEAD` file. What is the tertiary check?"